# Set focus to Entry control to trigger keyboard in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I'm trying to set focus to an `Entry` control when a page loads to automatically trigger the keyboard.

However, while the `Entry` control receives focus (caret blinking), if done during `Loaded` event, the keyboard doesn't appear.

If done only in the `Appearing` event, the caret doesn't even appear.

My page has a single `Entry` like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="RoundsEntry" Keyboard="Numeric" />
</StackLayout>
```

In the code-behind, I'm setting focus during the `Loaded` event:

```
public RoundsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += RoundsPage_Loaded;

    // For Shell navigation, the Appearing event makes more sense, 
    // as page is only loaded once, but we want the Entry control 
    // to receive focus every time the user returns to the page.
    Appearing += RoundsPage_Loaded;
}

private void RoundsPage_Loaded(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RoundsEntry.Focus();
}
```

Manually tapping the `Entry` control (even though it already has focus) does trigger the keyboard.

Am I missing something, or is there some other option to programmatically trigger (and later hide) the keyboard?

(Tested on Android.)

Edit: seems related to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5983), so I think I'm looking for a viable workaround until it's fixed.

Comment: What does the Loaded event do exactly?

Comment: @FreakyAli AFAIK it happens when the visual element has loaded but it's not yet being rendered, that instead happens during the `Appearing` event.

Comment: You can add `RoundsEntry.Focus();` to `Appearing` method.

Comment: @JianweiSun The problem is getting the keyboard to appear automatically to enter data into the default `Entry` control.

Comment: Could you provide some code about Loaded event ?

Comment: @JianweiSun The code above shows attaching an event handler to the `Loaded` event. All `VisualElement` types have it. Not much documentation about it, though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.visualelement.loaded?view=net-maui-6.0

Comment: I test code, and it run correctly  . Which version you used android API and MAUI or other things？

Comment: @JianweiSun The issue is confirmed reproducible: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5983 Are you able to show/hide the on-screen keyboard by setting focus to an `Entry` element?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I create a MAUI project and run the code you provided. I can show/hide the on-screen keyboard by setting focus to an `Entry` element. By the I test the code with android API 32/33, they all can achieve effect.

Comment: Did you use physical machine or virtual?

Comment: API 32, both virtual and physical devices. How/when do you set focus? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a question or a bug of which piece of version. Such as Visual Studio, .NET ...

Here is the code：

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

   private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry.Focus();
    }
}
```

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout>        
    <Entry x:Name="entry" Keyboard="Numeric"/>    
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

> **VS**: Community 2022 (64-bit) 17.3.4
> --- **.NET**:6.0 --- **Android**: API 32

This is my [screen recording](https://i.imgur.com/YTpXrqY.mp4)

Comment: Thanks for testing! Does the keyboard also disappear when invoking `Unfocus()`? For example if you, after a delay of say 2 seconds, call `entry.Unfocus()` or shift the focus to some other element? You could also try adding another `Entry` element (with a different `Keyboard` property value) to your XAML and switch focus programmatically between them to see if the correct keyboard appears.

Comment: @TedNyberg Keyboard can't disappear when invoking `Unfocus()`, unless click `Esc`, I think there are some logics I didn't expect required code implementation. In addition, switching focus programmatically between different `Entry` is ok. [video](https://imgur.com/a/VOajyWO)

Comment: Please accept it ✅ as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regrettably it's not a solution, it's still a verified bug. Also, doing this during `Appearing` ignores the focus completely (not even a caret in the textbox). I clarified this in OP.

Comment: I tested `Appearing` before, and it doesn't work the same as [the issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5983) indeed. 

Comment: this solution did not work for me

Comment: this is very outrageous that to date it still does not work

Comment: @TedNyberg To hide the keyboard and unfocus, I wrote a static function like below, maybe will be useful for someone else:

public static class Helpers
    {
        public static void HideKeyboard(bool Unfocus = true)
        {
#if ANDROID
            if (Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus != null)
            {
                Platform.CurrentActivity.HideKeyboard(Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus);
                if (Unfocus)
                    Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus.ClearFocus();
            }
#endif
        }
    }

Comment: Can we set focus in XAML as well? I couldn't find a property to set.

Answer (score 4):

This was bugging me for a while now.

It seems the Loaded event is too soon to be setting focus.
i couldn't find another event after 'loaded' so the dirty work around that worked for me is building in a slight delay.

```cs
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage {
  public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
  }

  private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _ = Task.Delay(200).ContinueWith(t =>{
      entry.Focus();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Dirty but effective! It also works in OnAppearing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Visual Studio, XAML or .NET MAUI bug at all. It is an architectural concept in the way which .NET MAUI loads views and triggers events. Somehow, the the parent view Loaded event only gets triggered when the view itself loads and not its children views. Suppose we have a content page as following:

```
<ContentPage ...
    Loaded="OnPageLoaded">

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="RoundsEntry" Keyboard="Numeric" />
    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void OnPageLoaded(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page loaded");
    RoundsEntry.Focus();
}
```

If you open the output window in Visual Studio, you will see the above log in there, but you will not have the keyboard triggered up. Why? Basically, because the entry view itself has not been fully loaded; as we said before, the Loaded event gets fired when the view itself gets loaded and nothing else.
Now, if we intend to perform an action for a specific view like setting or unsetting focus, we have to listen for Loaded event on that particular view.

```
<ContentPage ...>

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="RoundsEntry" Keyboard="Numeric"
        Loaded="RoundsEntrySetFocus"/>
    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void RoundsEntrySetFocus(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RoundsEntry loaded");
    RoundsEntry.Focus();
}
```

If you run the app, you will see the above log in the output window, and the keyboard will get triggered up. The same concept applies for the Editor and all other views. This behavior is consistent across various mobile platforms, including Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did on `OnAppearing` of `xaml.cs` file

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   txtName.Loaded += delegate { txtName.Focus(); };
}
```

`txtName` is Name of `Entry` control.